# How to set external SQS Queue reference for aws-eventbridge-sqs CDK construct?

Tags: amazon-sqs, aws-cdk

I am using AWS Solutions Constructs library to define an EventBridge Rule for linking an EventBus with SQS queue, i.e.: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/constructs/aws-eventbridge-sqs.html

As the documentation states, it is possible to either define parameters for SQS Queue that would be created by the CDK Construct or a reference of an existing queue can be passed over. I am trying to use the later approach with Python CDK App and use that parameter:

```
Name                Type
existingQueueObj?   sqs.Queue
```

The issue is, I have access just to a queue ARN that I can use to create an `IQueue` interface using `sqs.Queue.from_queue_arn` CDK function which does not comply with the requested type here so I am getting following error:

```
TypeError: type of argument existing_queue_obj must be one of (aws_cdk.aws_sqs.Queue, NoneType); got aws_cdk.aws_sqs._QueueBaseProxy instead
```

Any hints on how to potentially use that construct and properly set the reference to an already existing Queue?

Comment: Correct, but I would like to set a reference to an existing Queue. It looks like I need to hand over the full `Queue` object though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Existing` is a misnomer, it means that the queue exists in your CDK app, as opposed to being created by the `EventbridgeToSqs` construct. You cannot use an imported Queue, that's why the expected type is `Queue`, not `IQueue`.

`from_queue_arn` returns an instance of `IQueue`, not `Queue`, and cannot be used here.